# Must declare the scalar variable pivot sql query

Tags: sql, variables, sql-server-2012, pivot

i am generating  attendance report by pivot SQL on the basis of data thought thumb impression but the query shows error 
Must declare the scalar variable "@abc".
here is my query

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @abc NVARCHAR(MAX)


set  @abc='00:00'
 SELECT  


  top 1   @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(varchar, DateIn ,106 )    
            + ']','[' + CONVERT(varchar, DateIn ,106) + ']'  )       
              FROM    DailyAttendanceMaster  where 
                DateIn between '2019-01-01  00:00:00.000' and '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'  
                  group by  DateIn order by DateIn asc   
   DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(4000) SET  
     @qry = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT Employee_Master.Employee_Name, 
       case when convert(char(5), TimeIn, 108)= convert(char(5),  @abc, 108) then "A"
        else "B"
        end "TimeIn"  , 
        DailyAttendanceMaster.DateIn FROM DailyAttendanceMaster inner 
        join Employee_Master on Employee_Master.essl_EmpID=DailyAttendanceMaster.EMPID)emp  
              PIVOT (MAX(TimeIn) FOR DateIn IN (' + @cols + ')) AS stat'    
                  EXEC(@qry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass variable:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @qry, N'@abc NVARCHAR(MAX)', @abc
```

Comment: @NivasKhatal You are using in dynamic query `case when convert(char(5), TimeIn, 108)= convert(char(5),  @abc, 108) then "A"` variable that was not declared

Comment: @NivasKhatal Not in a context of dynamic query

Comment: is  any other option to do this